# Dashboard in monitor network layer

Tags: networking, byte, osi

I have seen many monitoring dashboards monitor and measure the Bytes in and out data for network layer message length as shown. 
[image]

What is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

being aware of the bandwidth consumption is useful to detect and act in cases such as DDos attacks, bad network management, optimizing networks usage reducing time responses and so on.
Bandwidth consumption is one of the key aspects to bare in mind managing networks
Hope it helps

Comment: Does that mean if there is unusual events like DDOS, the bytes input or output will be extra large?

Comment: They will increase, sure thing